# Echoing a "set" into a batch file without quotes

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to do the following, which isn't working as intended:

```
echo set value=0>test.bat
```

It's parsing in the command window as:

```
echo set value= 0>test.bat
```

Which is causing it to echo "set value= " and 0>test.bat

Is there a way around this without using double quotes? (I.E.)

```
 echo "set value=0">test.bat
```

I want to be able to just run test.bat, without having to parse the batch file and remove quotes. The only work around I can think is to parse the file and overwrite it with the non-quoted block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the DOS or CMD version, the 0 can be escaped with ^, like this:

```
C:\> echo set value=^0>test.bat
C:\> type test.bat
set value=0
```

Comment: This fixed it. I had tried escaping the = sign, but hadn't tried escaping the 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the redirection anywhere in a statement.  In this case, putting it at the beginning solves your problem.

```
>test.bat echo set value=0
```